# How to programmatically add uibutton action?

Tags: swift, uibutton, segue

I have created a button and I was wondering how do I programmatically code an action for the UIButton to take me to another view controller?

This is all I have so far:

```
let getStartedButton: UIButton = {
    let getStartedButton =  UIButton()
    getStartedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.51, blue:0.59, alpha:1.0)
    getStartedButton.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
    getStartedButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 18)
    getStartedButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    getStartedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    return getStartedButton
}()

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("...")
}
```

Comment: The code you posted already properly add a UIButton action programmatically so what is your real question/isse?

Comment: As it says in the title... I want to present another view controller by pressing the uibutton I created.

Comment: Then why does the title ask how to add a button action if you already know how to add the button action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the transition to another ViewController after pressing the button, you can do this in 2 ways:

1) [present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! SecondViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

2) [pushViewController(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller)

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I've tried the codes and I receive this error:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can show a new View Controller:

1. Presenting View Controller:

   ```
   @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
       let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController") as! DestinationViewController
       self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
2. Performing a Segue from Storyboard:

If you already have the View Controller you want to present in your Storyboard, and it has a segue from your origin VC to your destination VC, then you can add an identifier to the segue and do this...

```
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    }
```

3. Pushing View Controller onto Stack (this only works if your original VC is embedded in a Navigation Controller):

   ```
   @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
       let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController") as! DestinationViewController
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
   }
   ```

Comment: I've tried the codes and I receive this error:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)